# ClassCastException with Spring Cloud and Kafka Streams

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am starting a new SB app that will act as a consumer for Kafka, and I started to play with Kafka Streams, but I am getting the following exception when starting the app

> **java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101 cannot be cast to class org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel** (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101 and org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindConsumer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:91) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindConsumer(AbstractBinder.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
> at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleConsumerBinding$1(BindingService.java:201) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
> at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:an]

This is how I have declared the KStream that counts how many time a word is sent:

```
@Bean
  public Consumer<KStream<Bytes, String>> target() {
    return input -> input.flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
        .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value, value))
        .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
        .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(30000))).count(Materialized.as("words-count"))
        .toStream().map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(null, new WordCount(key.key(), value,
            new Date(key.window().start()), new Date(key.window().end()))));
  }
```

Using the same application.yml and having a Consumer function for only receiving the messages like this

```
@Bean
  public Consumer<Message<String>> target() {
    return message -> {
      System.out.println("******************");
      System.out.println("Received message from source: " + message.getPayload());
    };
  }
```

everything works fine.

I am using the following versions:

- SpringBoot v2.4.4
- SpringCloud v.2020.0.2
- Java v11.0.10

I have seen other posts with this error during unit tests, but I have not even had any Junit test yet.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the Kafka Streams binder in the classpath, but the message channel binder. Make sure that you have the dependency `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams` on the classpath.